# gitlab API - deployment stats

Tags: api, gitlab, gitlab-api

I'm trying to retrieve information/stats on my gitlab account.
According to Gitlab API, you can retrieve total number of successful deployment stats on each different projects - https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/deployments.html
This method is done by individual project base.

I was wondering if theres any way to grab total number of successful deployments in the account overall?

Answer (score 0):

As of Gitlab version 13.9, there is no API to grab deployments other than for a single project. Also, it doesn't appear anyone has asked for this feature according to their [issues](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues?scope=all&utf8=%E2%9C%93&state=all&search=%22deployments+api%22), but you can always submit a feature request.